# Dynamic profile based website that also has hard links?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

Ok, so I'm building a website that has client profiles. A web user finds these mysql profiles via a search function. The profile page is one php page that loads all the mysql data via the #id number that is passed through the address. This is all great, but my clients, based on hte business model and needs, are going to need to be able to have their profile tied to a hard address that looks nice and doesn't have variable data included in it.

Let me explain with an example. Imagine the site is called bizprofiles.com. A user searches the DB and clicks on a link from the search display. The search is just putting the ID number in the variable, so the address might resemble this:

http://www.bizprofiles.com/profile.php?id=1002937

The business isn't going to want to put an address out there like that when they want customers to visit the site, so I'm wondering how I can have a hard address that somehow still loads the profile page with the mysql data. So the biz can have an address like this:

http://www.bizprofiles.com/bizname

Keep in mind that I've built this site using PHP and MYSQL. Thanks in advance for any insight you can give me!

Comment: could you use server side URL rewriting? do you have apache?

Comment: can you retag it as `.htaccess` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign each profile a `unique-name` (username, provably) and map it to the `profile_id` in the database.

**EDIT:**

Well here's the basic idea:
You need to have `.htaccess` file at the doc-root containing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
```

What above code does is: converts the url like `http://www.bizprofiles.com/profile/bizname` to `http://www.bizprofiles.com/profile.php?user=bizname`

So what you need to do now is update `profile.php` to display profile on the basis of this `unique-name` available in `$_GET["user"]`.

Comment: Ok, but then how does the server know what to do? I mean, how does the server use this incoming slug to query the DB?

Comment: You might also want to read more about [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: Thanks so much ssapkota! I wanted to let the users pick their url anyways, so I'm just going to add it to the profile registration process and just have a simple check for duplicate slugs.

Comment: So after trying to get my head around the rewrite engine a bit more, I realize that these conditions are going to test of the file or directory exists, if it doesn't, it rewrites the url without actually changing it in the users window (i've tested this). So if anyone ever types in any address that does not actually exist, it's going to redirect it to the profile page, correct?

Comment: And if I don't want it to behave this way, I'm going to have to add a conditional string to the URL, for example:

http://www.bizprofiles.com/profiles/bizprofileuniquename

And write a condition that checks that the URL matches the format exactly up until the bizprofileuniquename? Theres probably not any other real way of going about it? I'm going to have to have the profile page send the user to an error page if the query fails regardless. Say the visitor is trying to go to the contact page, and enters an incorrect url, it will try to send the user to the profile page. It seems sloppy.

Comment: @Jacob, I have updated accordingly. The url for profile is now `.../profile/<alphanumeric-username>`. This isn't sloppy anymore. is it?  You might also want to read more on mod_rewrite - [start here](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_rewrite+apache).

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep so called "slug" in the database. Your table "customers" needs to store a unique name that will be used to produce a link. See Facebook, it lets you assign the name you want.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug